# Why we use singleton class?

Tags: javascript, loops, design-patterns

I am new to OOPs concept. I have understood singleton class. But, can somebody help me to understand the use of singleton class.

Can we say this is a singleton class in javascript?

```
var user = {  
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    sayName: function() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
};
```

Comment: This must be a duplicate of something, but the hallmark of a singleton class is that the constructor is private, and it can only be instantiated once.  A singleton makes sense when you want there to be only one instance of an object at some point in your program.  Google around and you will find many things.  Jon Skeet has a singleton named after him.

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't get too comfortable with singletons. Try *not* to use them.

Comment: Most important is to ask why we don't use singletons. It is easy to see why not to make "logger" or "config" as singleton.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for google.

Answer (score 3):

The `singleton` pattern should be used when there must be exactly one instance of a class, and  it must be accessible to clients from a global access point.

**Few examples**

```
Logger Classes
```

The Singleton pattern is used in the design of logger classes. This classes are ussualy implemented as a singletons, and provides a global logging access point in all 
the application components without being necessary to create an object each time a logging operations is performed.

```
Configuration Classes
```

The Singleton pattern is used to design the classes which provides the configuration settings for an application. By implementing configuration classes as Singleton not only that we provide a global access point,

There are many examples..

we should **resist** ourselves from using it until and unless there is a strong requirement for it because of the **unpredictable** nature of the results in the **multi-threading environment.**

Comment: In C++11 with a Meyer's Singleton a lot of the threading problems are eliminated.